# If I increase the bcrypt cost do I have to rehash the users password already registered?

Tags: symfony, passwords, bcrypt

I'm just digging into Symfony2 and just got my own user-provider running. ATM I use brypt with a cost of 12. If I now increase the cost, bcrypt should rehash the password again!?! But how can I persist the new    password to database?

Comment: Are you looking to also rehash all existing user passwords automatically, or force password update, or just this one off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the cost in any moment because as you can read in the [official symfony2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#using-the-bcrypt-password-encoder) you don't need to rehash the old passwords because they are automatically handled with the old cost (and if you want you can force the users in the future to change their password like happens in many large sites).

Comment: Do you know if there a method to check if the password uses the current cost?

Comment: I don't know if there is such method but I think for you is more useful adding a method (possibly event-fired) to force users to change their password every 3/4 months.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't reverse a hash function so you're left with two options:**

1. Force on user to insert new password or...
2. Update the hash as users login to your system again (You can force to kick the cookie and sessions that allows the user to log in without retyping their password). This solution will allow your users to log in with the old hash and at the same time you will update the old hash with the new one. Next time your user will log in, the script will use the new version of the hash to login the user.

In this example, I have used md5 as a hash and I want to update it to BCRYPT with cost = 12 but feel free to change it to what ever you need. Change from BCRYPT cost=10 to BCRYPT cost = 12 would also work or any other combination. Consider this example:

```
$passwordFromDatabase = "0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7"; // md5  hash of "letmein"
$passwordFromForm = $_POST['password']; // $_POST['password'] == "letmein"

if(password_needs_rehash($passwordFromDatabase, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => 12]) && md5($passwordFromForm) === $passwordFromDatabase){
    // generate new password
    $newPasswordHash = password_hash($passwordFromForm, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ["cost" => 12]);
    // update hash from databse - replace old hash $passwordFromDatabase with new hash $newPasswordHash
    // after update login user
    if(password_verify($passwordFromForm, $newPasswordHash)){
        // user has logged in successfully and hash was updated
        // redirect to user area
    }else{
        // ups something went wrong Exception
    }
}else{
    if(password_verify($passwordFromForm, $passwordFromDatabase)){
        // user password hash from database is already BCRYPTed no need to rehash
        // user has logged in successfully
        // redirect to user area
    }else{
        // wrong password
        // no access granted - stay where you are
    }
}
```

I prefer the second option :). Make your own choice. If you pick the second option and choose not to kick the cookie and session that allow user to login without providing the password, it's OK too... The change will happen overtime. And no one will even notice the change.

Comment: I think you made some mistakes: 1) You check for password_needs_rehash _and_ md5, shouldn't it be an _or_ instead? 2) When you hash the password anew, it doesn't make sense to do a password_verify afterwards, or don't you trust the hash function? 3) It should be `password_verify()` instead of password_veryfi.

Comment: 1.) well password_needs_rehash(..., ..., ...) will return true if it find the difference and md5 will return true if the user provide correct password. So i think that should be fine. If I use "OR" instead "AND" user would go throu to set new password even if he provide wrong password. Is that not correct ? 2.) Well i gues you could omit password_veryfi(..., ...) if the user provide correct md5. But this is just to make sure that everything went correct and there is new hash in database thats all. You dont need to do it. 3.) corrected the typo thx

Comment: The order is indeed a bit special, first one should check whether the password is correct, and only then one should check whether rehashing is necessary, see the example from the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php). If you combine password_needs_rehash and MD5 with an _and_, you won't be able to detect future requirements for rehashing.